# PHP - PDO - JQuery dynamic select element only allows the first option to be selected

Tags: php, jquery, pdo

For certain reasons (towards a larger picture), I have a select element that is populated by a php page. The data is populated properly within the element. However, when I make a selection the element always forces the first item in the list. If I "append" the returned data, I can select different items but if clicked again it will just keep appending on top of the existing items. If I "empty" before the "append" it shows the correct list but still forces the first item in the list and this happens whether I use onclick or onchange. Whatever code works will also need to be applied the same to this element being dynamically created on the same page later. As I understand it the $(document).on('click'... as opposed to  $(document).click(... works better for dynamic elements. Any help is appreciated. Thanks, I am still new to this exchange and I hope I described my problem correctly. I have searched for hours about this problem, but I mostly get results about multiple select elements or populating a second select, and even potential answers I have tried do not work.

My data is pulled from _get_staffnames.php, and lets say it shows Frank, George, Todd.

```
    $stmt = $myPDO->prepare( "SELECT userID, CONCAT(firstname,' ', lastname) AS Fullname FROM tbl_user ORDER BY Fullname ASC" );
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();   

    foreach ($results as $row): 
        echo '<option value="' . $row['userID'] . '">' . $row['Fullname'] . '</option>';
    endforeach
```

My HTML is:

```
    <select name="userID1" id="userID1" class="namesClass" required>
        <option selected value="">Select Staff</option>
    </select>
```

One JQuery way I tried, specifically for the one element id "userID1", populates Frank, George, Todd...but when I pull down and click Todd, it still shows Frank (first in list) after the click.

```
    $("#userID1").click(function() {
        $("#userID1").load("_get_staffnames.php");
    });
```

More towards the dynamic way I am going. This code allows me to choose Frank, George, or Todd and keeps the selection, but if I click on that given dynamic element again, the list keeps repeating the group +1 every time I click on it.

```
    $(document).on('click', '.namesClass', function(e) { 
        var select_id = $(this).attr("name");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '_get_staffnames.php',
            })
            .done(function (returndata) {
                $('#' + select_id).append(returndata);
            })
    });
```

When I try the .empty parameter before append as below, I get the correctly populated list (without multiple appended groups) but when I choose any item it always defaults to the first item in the list (Frank) again.

```
    $(document).on('click', '.namesClass', function(e) { 
        var select_id = $(this).attr("name");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '_get_staffnames.php',
            })
            .done(function (returndata) {
                $('#' + select_id).empty().append(returndata);
            })
    });
```

Comment: Not sure I follow what you want to do. So you click on a name in the select, and then use ajax to append the list again? You are not sending any data with your ajax. Are you trying to filter the results? Can show and example or create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example of what your are trying to do?

Comment: Basically, I want my select element to allow me to choose any item and then show that I have chosen that item. The element is populated, but when I click on an item and then off, it just defaults to the first item.  I haven't done a jsFiddle example yet, so I am unfamiliar with that process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is clicking on the `Select` element the only way you can load data from a remote source?

It's totally unconventional and by doing so, you are triggering the `onclick` event and performing the `ajax` method every time you click on any item of it which will eventually recreate its child elements on every callback and thus the first item being selected as default.

Comment: Thanks, your absolutely right, I guess I needed to step away from it for a bit. I fixed it in my answer by checking if the element has anything in it before running AJAX. I have created a continuous form where the select element is dynamically added by the user when they add a new row and I needed a way to populate it and any others that were added after the document load. This works now, but I am open to any  suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As kolunar pointed out, even when I clicked on my selection I was running ajax again. So, I just check if there is anything in the element before running ajax and it works. Feels silly now, but thanks for the time and input.

```
    $(document).on('click', '.namesClass', function(e) { 
        var select_id = $(this).attr("name");

        if ( $('#' + select_id).val() == '' ) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '_get_staffnames.php',
                })
                .done(function (returndata) {
                    $('#' + select_id).empty().append(returndata);
                })
        }
    });
```